# Connect to MongoDB Docker image on VPS and Import large JSON file

Tags: mongodb, docker, vps

I have a mongodb docker container running on my 1and1 VPS port 27017:27017. The container's name is mongo. I need to connect to that already running container and import in a very large JSON file (backup db) of 11GB. Does anyone know how I could do this please? I have tried looking at a few other people's questions but none of them had the correct answer. Also the JSON file is already uploaded to the VPS so I'm guessing I need to include the correct path to that? Any help appreciated.

Comment: So i guess mounting a volume contains that large file wont be an option as it require rebuilding the container which might cause a down time for few seconds ?

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to do that. I have managed to get the docker image downloaded from the docker hub repo, installed and running but I don't know what command to use to connect to the container and then import the JSON file. Hence why I've asked the question. If I was able to connect to the docker container from NoSQLBooster for MongoDB remotely from my desktop computer I could use the import function from there but again can't do that either because I can't find anything on how to do it.

Comment: I understand, I will try to write an detailed answer and let's see if it fits your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions that might fit:

- **Mounting the large file using volumes.** Let's say that you are using the following command to run the docker container

```
docker run --name mongodb mongo:latest
```

And the large file is inside this path on your host `/backup/mongo/largefile.json`, In order to mount this file inside the container you need to start a new container instead of the already running one, so you are free to stop the old container before running a new one using these commands:

```
docker stop mongodb
docker rm mongodb
docker run --name mongodb -v /backup/mongo:/home/ mongo:latest
```

The commands above will stop the container named `mongodb` and then delete it and after that it will create a new container with the same name and mount this directory `/backup/mongo` into this path `/home` inside the container.
Finally if you have a specific shell script that will do the import for you after you mount the file you can add this script to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and it will be executed after the container start for the first time. and now the final command will be (**Modify the command as you see fit**):

> This command does not provide any data persistence to `/data/db` so you need to create a volume for it using `-v`

```
docker run --name mongodb -v /backup/mongo:/home/ -v /path/to/my/script:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ mongo:latest
```

To verify that the large file is inside the container you can use this command (assuming that container name is mongodb):

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
```

---

- **Connecting from your local machine to the container on your VPS**. As you mentioned in your comment that you might use a gui application located in your machine to do the import. In this case you need to consider the following:

  - Starting from Mongo 3.6 it wont be exposed publicly. so you need to tell it to be exposed using `mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0` appended to the end of the `docker run` command but I don't recommend to follow this method as it is not secure. Or you may use SSH tunneling which will connect you to the container IP.

---

My final recommendation is to follow the first method as the file already available on the VPS and no need to upload it again.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is just what I needed! A lot of answers pertain to docker on local machine not a VPS. Someone should really write up and video (for youtube) a complete tutorial of how to do this for people that have a VPS.

Comment: Mostafa I'm trying to connect via the NoSQLBooster GUI client but it just sits there until it finally times out. I've run the command you recommended with the `code` --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 and that worked fine, however the GUI won't connect. Is there any way we could converse over another medium other than this site?

Comment: Ok so quick update to this. I tried the following `docker exec <container-name-or-id> mongoimport -d <db-name> -c <c-name> --file /tmp/backup.json` and behold it started doing the import but then crashed out at 2.00GB with message: `fatal error out of memory` so not sure what to do now.

Comment: How much free memory do you have ?

Comment: 7.5GB according to usage

Comment: The problem is, that the file size is bigger than the memory size, so maybe thats why it says out of memory. I have no experience with this but maybe if you split the file or something like this. **Make sure to have a backup just in case**